# Uncommon UI layout for Windows installer for Techsmith Snagit

Tags: windows-installer

Does anyone know which windows installer/packager TechSmith Snagit v12 uses? The UI layout of the installer doesn't look like standard Windows Installer.
[image: Snagit installer GUI][image: Snagit installer GUI]

Comment: The questions to ask yourself is a) does your product really need a snazzy UI and b) what's it worth to the business?  Native MSI UI is long in the tooth but it can be used to provide a clean consistent experience.  Some industries really need the snazziness or can spread the cost of the work across multiple projects.  For many line of business apps it's simply not needed.

Comment: For a moment this UI made me wonder if Snagit is built on top of Electron.js. Looks like it isn't, or is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a native Windows Installer UI. It is an EXE bootstrapper which handles the UI, that **maybe** under the hood is running an MSI to perform the actual, but this is not mandatory.

Packages with such an GUI can be built with [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/download.html) too, using the [Surface theme](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/surface-screen-shot.html). You can have different colors, below is an example on black.

[image: Surface theme from Advanced Installer]

Answer (score 1):

As Bogdan already has explained, this is a small application that handles the GUI part of an installation suite (several installations in sequence as a bundle). MSI has a feature to allow an external GUI via its [**MsiSetExternalUI function**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370384(v=vs.85).aspx). This way you can handle **messages** returned from the Windows Installer engine yourself inside your own GUI - this includes the **progress bar**. [**Here is a technical example**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368786(v=vs.85).aspx).

You might also want to check the [**Wix Toolkit's Burn feature**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/).

***UPDATE***: [WIX Installer with modern look and feel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52344035/wix-installer-with-modern-look-and-feel/52349744#52349744)