# Wix - Choice of UI based on property

Tags: user-interface, wix, installation, windows-installer, wix-gui

In my **Wix** application, I want to have **2 different UI**. During execution, I want the choice of UI to be done depending of the value of a property. Is it possible to achieve this and how ?

Comment: You need to explain this better. What are you doing, and why is this needed?

Comment: I've got an msi launched with command line from a bootstrapper application. To launch this msi, the bootstrapper can have an option which is supposed to switch the msi's UI, but the msi's logic stays the same. I could build 2 different msi, but I'm wondering if there is a solution with only 1 msi. HTH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps what you need is to handle the GUI yourself inside your launcher application. This is possible via the [**MsiSetExternalUI function**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370384(v=vs.85).aspx).

See these previous answers:

- [Is there anyway to get msiexec to echo to stdout instead of logging to a file](https://serverfault.com/questions/434568/is-there-anyway-to-get-msiexec-to-echo-to-stdout-instead-of-logging-to-a-file/615256#615256)
- [Uncommon UI layout for Windows installer for Techsmith Snagit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687888/uncommon-ui-layout-for-windows-installer-for-techsmith-snagit/24700795#24700795)
- [How to interactive a silently installing msi? (Progress data and cancel it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659924/how-to-interactive-a-silently-installing-msi-progress-data-and-cancel-it/1661835#1661835)

***UPDATE***: [WIX Installer with modern look and feel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52344035/wix-installer-with-modern-look-and-feel/52349744#52349744)

Comment: Thank you, there is a lot of things to investigate (I thought it was simpler). Also doing a Bootstrapper with Burn looks appealing.

Comment: Things get complicated quickly. You did see the Advanced Installer feature in the link? It features at least some of what you need, though I have never used it for this sort of GUI.