# I need to remove feature selection screen from my wix installer

Tags: wix

I have created a setup using wix installer, During installations user must have to install all features from feature tree, So I don't want to display this feature option screen during installation. Is there any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

***Dialog Set***: You can select a dialog set without this dialog? [Default dialog sets](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_dialog_library.html). You are probably using **`Advanced`** or **`Mondo`**?

***Mandatory Features***: You can set all features to be mandatory? I guess you might already have done so. Then the user can not do any damage from the GUI (maybe they still can from msiexec.exe command line).

***Custom Dialogs***: You can create your own dialog set and take it out? [Some details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61160609/129130).

- [Minimalistic sample](https://github.com/glytzhkof/all/tree/master/WiXCustomDialog)
- [Zip version of Minimalistic sample](https://github.com/glytzhkof/all/blob/master/WiXCustomDialog.zip)