# Is there any way to change Option and Install button color in standard boot strapper

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn

I am using WIX theme file for my custom UI design. My requirement is to change "Install" and "Option" button color to green. IS there any tag for that

```
<Button Name="OptionsButton" X="-91" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0" HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.InstallOptionsButton)</Button>
<Button Name="InstallButton" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.InstallInstallButton)</Button>
```

I changed the font color but its not working

Comment: Some parts of a GUI is standard and might not be possible to change. I have not worked with GUI for quite some time, but [have a look at this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52674815/129130) - see screenshots first. Throwing in [one more link on MSI / Burn GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52349744/129130).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you meant the background of the button to be green, and not the text. You really should look up the schema I referenced in a different question of yours: https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/thmutil/button.html.

| Attribute | Description |
| --- | --- |
| ImageFile | Relative path to an image file to define an graphic button. The image must be 3x the height to represent the button in 3 states: unselected, hover, selected. Mutually exclusive with ImageResource and SourceX and SourceY attributes. |

Note that v4 has high DPI support which changed some image handling so make sure to look up that documentation when moving to v4.