# How show version number in title of installation in WIX?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wix, wix3

I need to display the version number in the title along with the application name.

Currently, it looks like

[image]

Here is my wix snippet:

```
<Product Id="$(var.ProductId)" Name="Test Application" Language="1033" Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Manufacturer="Test1111 Inc" 
       UpgradeCode="C9BC6B42-FCAF-4E96-8F8F-E9D0AC4F393B">
```

If I change it (append version number in the Name attribute) as below, it will display the version number in all the places Title, Welcome text/description but I just want to change in Title.

```
<Product Id="$(var.ProductId)" Name="Test Application $(var.ProductVersion)" Language="1033" Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Manufacturer="Test1111 Inc" 
       UpgradeCode="C9BC6B42-FCAF-4E96-8F8F-E9D0AC4F393B">
```

How we can accomplish this in Wix?

Comment: Not sure, that you can do using snippet above. MSI displays `ProductName` in standard dialogs. Probably, you'll need to create your own wix UI dialogs and put information on it

Comment: Thanks @PavelAnikhouski Is there any link/sample for this?

Comment: Try to follow wixui documentation http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/

Answer (score 7):

***Localization Override***: You can try to add a localization file and then override the **`WelcomeDlgTitle`** string ([**the WiX GUI string list / list of string identifiers can be found here**](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/WixUI_en-us.wxl) (for English):

1. Note that this assumes **the Mondo dialog set:**

   - Add to WiX markup: **`<UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />`**
   - Add reference to **`%ProgramFiles(x86)%\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\WixUIExtension.dll`**
   - [WiX Hello World Sample in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47972615/129130) (WiX markup with comments towards bottom is usually enough for developers to get the gist of things)
2. Right click your WiX project in Visual Studio **`=>`** Add **`=>`** New Item...
3. Select **`WiX v3`** in the left menu. Double click **`Localization file`** (very common to add a WiX v4 file instead, double check please)
4. Add the string below to the localization file:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <WixLocalization Culture="en-us" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization">
     <String Id="WelcomeDlgTitle">{\WixUI_Font_Bigger}Welcome to the [ProductName] [ProductVersion] Setup Wizard</String>
   </WixLocalization>
   ```
5. Compile and test

***Sample Dialog***:

### [image: Sample WiX Title Change]

***WiX GUI***: I am quite confused myself with **WiX GUI**, hence I wrote this little overview and "check list" to remember better (uses a similar approach to change the style of a dialog entry): **[Changing text color to Wix dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52654935/changing-text-color-to-wix-dialogs/52674815#52674815)**.

***Links***:

- ***WiX UI Sources:*** (languages strings and dialog sources)

  - https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib
- ***WiX UI English Strings:***

  - https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/WixUI_en-us.wxl
- ***WiX UI Norwegian Strings:***

  - https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/WixUI_nb-NO.wxl
- There are many such language files, use above link for full list

Answer (score 3):

WiX UI extension doesn't allow this type of customization.  Your two chances would be

1) define Name="Test Application $(var.ProductVersion)"   (Side effect. version listed in programs and features twice

2)  Stop using the WiXUI extension and instead clone all the code from https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib  into your project.

Comment: I've had some luck with localization files, but I am not sure if it is an "accepted approach". I have also tried to add items to existing dialogs, and I think I saw someone succeed, but I can't find it again.

Comment: It's pretty easy to add to the UI but very difficult to change something if a variation point override isn't already built in.

Comment: **MSI GUI**: total overkill, total anti-pattern. WiX does pretty well considering though. I wonder how limited the GUI could have been and been better? Just a few controls: edit, label, combo, checkbox, button and some simple events that worked would have done the trick. End of rant.

Comment: It's only overkill if everything is a micropackage and divorced from configuration.  I have many installs with nothing more the Welcome, Ready, Installing, Done but I also have ones that need more.  I generally find MSI UI acceptable for my needs.

Comment: I have always hated the problems with the events, but that is a bigger discussion. I wonder what will come next.