# How to show version number in title of MSI installer in WIX?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation

I want to show the version number only in the title and not anywhere else. Not even in the "Welcome to the XYZ setup wizard" line. By changing the name in the product line`<Product Name="$(var.productName) $(var.ProductVersion)"...>`

has a lot of side effects. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: [You seem to have tried this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55229627/129130)? What do you mean with title? The top left corner of the dialog top border?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***String Override***: In case you mean the title bar at the top (see screenshot below), you can try to override the string id **`"WelcomeDlg_Title"`** (as opposed to **`WelcomeDlgTitle`** - yes they are different, look closely) - and do this for [all string entries](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/WixUI_en-us.wxl) that end in **`_Title`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WixLocalization Culture="en-us" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization">

  <...>

  <String Id="WelcomeDlg_Title">[ProductName] - [ProductVersion]</String>

  <String Id="SetupTypeDlg_Title">[ProductName] - [ProductVersion]</String>
  <String Id="WelcomeEulaDlg_Title">[ProductName] - [ProductVersion]</String>
  <String Id="BrowseDlg_Title">[ProductName] - [ProductVersion]</String>
  <String Id="CancelDlg_Title">[ProductName] - [ProductVersion]</String>
  <String Id="CustomizeDlg_Title">[ProductName] - [ProductVersion]</String>
  <String Id="LicenseAgreementDlg_Title">[ProductName] - [ProductVersion]</String>
  <String Id="VerifyReadyDlg_Title">[ProductName] - [ProductVersion]</String>
  <String Id="WaitForCostingDlg_Title">[ProductName] - [ProductVersion]</String>

  <...etc...>

</WixLocalization>
```

***Summary***: All you need to do is as follows:

- Set up a WiX project in the normal way, add UI support: **`WixUIExtension.dll`**
- Add localisation file (for any number of languages)
- Override this string ID in all localization files and inject the version **`[ProductVersion]`**

***Existing Answer***: Rather than repeating the full procedure, please see this answer: [How show version number in title of installation in WIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55221550/how-show-version-number-in-title-of-installation-in-wix/55229627#55229627)

[image: Title]

Comment: It only changed the title on the first screen which you have shown in the screenshot. In the next screen, where License agreement is there again the name is the productName. I want to change the title on all the screens.

Comment: It sounded like that was what you wanted: "*...only in the title and not anywhere else*". Anyway, if you want that I think you need to customize the dialogs using more complex mechanisms as [described in my other answer to you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56279029/129130). It looks like the title might not be overridable for all standard dialogs.

Comment: @MehulParmar Updated the answer with a little hack that should get you what you ask for, but it is kind of messy, and it will only work for the title bar. You have to do it for all items that end in `_Title`. The list above is not complete.

Comment: [String list](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/WixUI_en-us.wxl).