# How to add image background to custom MSI dialog?

Tags: wix, wixsharp

I have a custom MSI dialog in my `wxs` file:

```
<Dialog Id="OpDialog" Width="300" Height="250" Title="[ProductName]: Operations">
    ...
</Dialog>
```

How can I set its background to some image file (bmp/png/...)?

Comment: Got this sorted?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul no, I don't think it's possible, unfortunately.

Comment: I believe the below should work?

Comment: Maybe try the [`WiXCustomDialog.zip` ad-hoc sample here](https://github.com/glytzhkof/all/). And [a direct link to zip](https://github.com/glytzhkof/all/blob/master/WiXCustomDialog.zip) (still need to click download I think).

Answer (score 1):

> ***Quick Link***: Hotlinking (direct link) a single page from WiX's own tutorial (also check the other pages): https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface-revisited/tuning-up/
>
> Sample WiX Markup Download: [SampleCustomUI](https://www.firegiant.com/system/files/samples/SampleCustomUI.zip)
>
> Not sure how this all behaves on high DPI screens.

---

***Generic Trick***: The WiX toolkit **`dark.exe`** tool can decompile an MSI file (`dark.exe -x Output File.msi`). You can use the decompiled files to figure out syntax that is poorly documented. I decompiled an MSI and combining it with the samples I linked to, you can try something like this (this does not show how to insert the dialog into a sequence, and I am not sure all constructs are good, but it compiles OK):

```
<!--<Binary Id="bannerbmp" SourceFile="Banner.bmp" />-->
<Binary Id="imagebmp" SourceFile="Image.bmp" />

<!--<Property Id="BannerBitmap">bannerbmp</Property>-->
<Property Id="ImageBitmap">imagebmp</Property>

<Dialog Id="ServerDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="Dialog Title">
  <!--<Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="[BannerBitmap]" />-->
  <Control Id="Image" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="374" Height="234" TabSkip="yes" Disabled="yes" Text="[ImageBitmap]" />

  <..>

</Dialog>
```

- Note that the above has a **BannerBitmap** (that is the one at the top going across the dialog) disabled and the whole dialog is now covered by the main image **ImageBitmap**.
- You can toggle the banner on easily if that is what you want to use. Just comment out the large image and enable the top banner.
- The above does not show proper localization - if you want to use localization files for translation.
- The above was simplified, I took out the WixVariable entry, see revision history if you want to see.

---

***Documentation***: WiX documentation on GUI customization: https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html

***Tutorial***: https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface-revisited/a-single-dialog/

---

***More Details***: Adding a link to a [larger description of WiX GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52674815/129130). Shows various tricks with WiX and MSI GUI.

***Samples***: Maybe some practical samples?

- https://helgeklein.com/blog/2014/09/real-world-example-wix-msi-application-installer
- [And a rather random sample found on github.com](https://github.com/s-nakaoka/choreonoid/tree/8ecf3e4c6b090f418817d826ce08d7d0b2cf229b/misc/build/msi-buildtool) - [the actual dialog markup](https://github.com/s-nakaoka/choreonoid/blob/8ecf3e4c6b090f418817d826ce08d7d0b2cf229b/misc/build/msi-buildtool/CustomLicense.wxs).

Comment: I found nothing related to **custom MSI dialog** background image. I learned a lot about styling text, which was very beneficial (and took advantage of), but nothing about background. Again - these links only tell you how to change the **default dialogs** background, not the **custom** dialogs.

Comment: OK, it was a bit rushed last night, have a quick look at the updates please.