# WiX: How to call UAC on "Repair"?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, elevated-privileges, repair

How can I show privilege escalation window on button "Repair"?

```
    <Control Id="RepairButton" ElevationShield="yes" Type="PushButton" X="40" Y="118" Width="80" Height="17" ToolTip="!(loc.MaintenanceTypeDlgRepairButtonTooltip)" Text="!(loc.MaintenanceTypeDlgRepairButton)">
      <Publish Event="Reinstall" Value="ALL" />
      <Publish Property="WixUI_InstallMode" Value="Repair">1</Publish>
      <Publish Property="TYPE_DESCRIPTION" Value="repair">1</Publish>
      <Publish Property="TYPE_DESCRIPTION2" Value="repair">1</Publish>
    </Control>
```

[image]

Comment: What dialog set is this? Afraid I can't look at this now, just lobbing a link: [WiX GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52654935/changing-text-color-to-wix-dialogs/52674815#52674815). Might not help much.

Comment: This is a set of customized UI .msi by WIX, when you click on the button "Change" in Control Panel -> Program and Features.