# How to customize welcome dialog in wix installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I want to add customized message in welcome screen instead of default in wixUI_en-us.wxl. For this I am trying to change <String Id="WelcomeDlgDescription"

Created a new wxl file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WixLocalization Culture="en-us" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization">

<String Id="WelcomeDlgDescription" Overridable="yes">This is a custom welcome message. Click Next to continue or Cancel to exit.</String>

</WixLocalization>
```

But I am not sure what WiX Fragment I need to enter in my WSX file

https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixdev/extensions/localized_extensions.html
https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/make_installer_localizable.html

Above both link I tried but not able to add the fragment in wsx file for "WelcomeDlgDescription"

Can you please guide what code should go in product.wsx to show my custome message

Comment: Thanks for the link, but its about custom dialog, I dont want to add any new dialog instead need to change the strign in welcome dialog

Comment: [Maybe check this answer quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52654935/changing-text-color-to-wix-dialogs/52674815#52674815).

Answer (score 0):

`<String Id="WelcomeDlgDescription">This is a custom welcome message. Click Next to continue or Cancel to exit.</String>`

You were close. I grabbed this from the [WiX page for changing default dialogs](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html).

https://github.com/glytzhkof/WiXCustomDialog