# WIx Installer: is there any way to auto close installer shield after successful installation

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, wix3.7

I want to auto close installer window on successful installation without pressing final close button.
Using wix installer can we able to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Installation Result***: This dialog is generally there to show whether the installation completed successfully or not - hence it is not a good idea to remove it. In fact there are usually several such exit dialogs: **`FatalError`**, **`UserExit`** and **`ExitDialog`** - depending on how the setup ended. Use **Orca** and go to: **`Tools => Dialog Preview`** to see what the dialogs look like.

***Customize GUI***: You can, however, remove the dialog from the sequence by customizing the standard WiX dialog set to be as you want it yourself. You can also remove all dialogs from an MSI, but not adding a default dialog set, but that is not recommended.

- [Some pointers on WiX GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52654935/changing-text-color-to-wix-dialogs/52674815#52674815)
- Here is a sample on customizing WiX dialogs: https://github.com/glytzhkof/WiXCustomDialog
- Here is a standard WiX GUI dialog set in use: https://github.com/glytzhkof/WiXDefaultDialogsSample (you can remove the dialogs by commenting out [this line](https://github.com/glytzhkof/WiXDefaultDialogsSample/blob/main/WiXDefaultDialogsSample/Product.wxs#L11) - then your setup has no dialogs except system dialogs).